# Save and load the classes definition table in the QGIS reclassify by table tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, reclassify

I'm reclassifying an aspect raster which cells values ranges from 0 to 359.999 using the `Reclassify by table` tool:

[image: reclassify tool parameters]

Setting the reclassification table manually is painful, especially when you have many classes:

[image: reclassification table values]
The two first lines in the reclassify table among many others...
But I see no way to either save or load the class definitions. Surprisingly.

Is it possible to save/load a custom definition of many classes to/from a file in order not to have to re-write them all each time this tool is re-open?

Info:
QGIS version: 3.16.3-Hannover
QGIS code revision: 94ac9f21b8

Answer (score 8):

This is a workaround using **Reclassify by layer** tool (so it is not a direct answer to your query).

(1) Prepare a classification table by a spreadsheet software ( I used MS-Excel).

[image]

(2) Drag and Drop the Excel file to the QGIS then it will appear on the TOC (Layers Panel).

[image]]

(3) Start **Reclassify by layer** tool and select *Min*, *Max* and *Output* fields from the table.

[image]

(4) Then Run the tool.

[image]

Hopefully someone will enhance the **Reclassify by table** tool to be able to load the outside files...