# Passing list as reclassify input table parameter in qgis.reclassifybytable algorithm

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, reclassify

Following up on [Save and load the classes definition table in the QGIS reclassify by table tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387970), I decided to run the [`qgis.reclassifybytable`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#reclassify-by-table) algorithm using [PyQGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html) to reclassify an [aspect](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasterterrainanalysis.html?highlight=aspect#aspect) raster.

Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import processing

l = np.hstack([np.arange(1,5,1),1])
t = np.hstack([np.arange(-90,360,90)[1:]])
t = np.repeat(t,2)
t = np.hstack([0,t,360])
L = list(np.insert(t,np.arange(2,len(t)+2,2),l))

input_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Aspect')[0]
output_layer = '/tmp/reclassify_output.tif'
params = {
  'DATA_TYPE': 5,
  'INPUT_RASTER': input_layer,
  'NODATA_FOR_MISSING': False, 
  'NO_DATA': -9999,
  'OUTPUT': output_layer,
  'RANGE_BOUNDARIES': 2,
  'RASTER_BAND': 1,
  'TABLE': L # <---- I'd like to pass a list here!
}

alg_id = 'qgis:reclassifybytable'
processing.run(alg_id, params)
```

Which gives this traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 159, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 71, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Invalid output value:
```

I particularly do like the `Invalid output value:` with nothing after! And the `OUTPUT` value is actually perfectly valid.

It took me some time to actually figure out a way that works, but with which I'm not 100% satisfied; copy-pasting the value of the list `L` that is printed on the console when I simply barely hit "L" in the Python console to show the content of this variable and to naively put it where `L` is used in the `params` variable in my code:

```py
>>> L
[0, 0, 1, 0, 90, 2, 90, 180, 3, 180, 270, 4, 270, 360, 1]
```

And this works.

So I thought that maybe, for some reason, the algorithm is waiting for a string at this position, so I also try to enter `str(L)` instead of simply `L` but then:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 159, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 71, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Invalid value for minimum: [0.0
```

Sounds very strange. It looks like it stops after reading the first value of the list.

Does anybody know what's going on here and how could I programmatically pass my list to the function `params` instead of entering it manually?